# Closing terminal closes the application called through nohup

Tags: terminal, signals, xterm, exit, nohup

As far as I know, `nohup` signals ignores *SIGHUP* signal sent by the terminal to the application but the application can change that.

I'm running Spotify through the command `nohup spotify &` and when I close the terminal by clicking the X symbol on the top corner of the terminal, so does Spotify.

1. Does this mean Spotify changes it so that it won't ignore *SIGHUP* signal?
   However, when I close the terminal using `exit` command, Spotify remains working.
2. Is the terminal sent different signal when `exit` command is called? I'd expect the Spotify to terminate as well.

P.S. I am using Elementary OS Loki and xterm.

Comment: The usual pitfall is that the application exits because its output has been closed.  You might try redirecting its output (including *stderr*) to `/dev/null` (ditto for its input).

Comment: @ThomasDickey,s hint is wrong in this case because nohup already handles io, and this does not account for exit working correctly.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I tried your suggestion just in case but all is same. Also as hildred pointed out, the output goes to nohup.out

Comment: @ThomasDickey I knew your name was familiar, I was just checking xterm's Wikipedia page and saw that you are maintaining it. I'd like to know your input further on it.

Comment: xterm sends SIGHUP (although your window manager could send SIGTERM).  It's done in [`Cleanup`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/0196678e37b232d4c29cd7eb6ebff20a868ce98e/misc.c#L5282).

Comment: gnome-terminal suffers from this same issue, see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=168320 and its duplicates. Redirecting the three standard file descriptors to /dev/null doesn't change a thing for me. I'd also love to understand what is exactly going on, I haven't had time to track it down. You can use `disown`, e.g. `nohup spotify & disown` (probably `nohup` isn't even needed then) as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Now since you did not say which terminal you were using, I cannot be sure, but The terminal is probably sending a SIGTERM or something else instead of a SIGHUP when it is closed. Three things to do are to read the man page for your terminal emulator, try a different terminal emulator, and to file a bug report on the terminal emulator.

P.S. Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: I tagged it with xterm but it is easy to miss so I edited the question as well.

Comment: Well `xterm`'s man page says that it sends SIGHUP when the quit action is invoked, but it also has actions to send any signal and I did not see which is called when it gets a destroy event from the window manager. This may be something you can adjust with resources, but I don't know for sure.